# How can I find a security group's dependencies?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

There is a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/546012/how-to-determine-aws-security-group-dependencies) that didn't receive a proper answer. How can I find a security group's dependencies?

These include EC2 instances, but other services also create dependencies, like the load balancer and even relationships with other security groups. Is there a way to systematically list every single dependency?

Thanks!